# An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in System.dll

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4

My visual basic application (targeting Framework 4) was running perfectly until I added code that was originally targeted for Framework 2.0 (specifically altering the column headers of a datagridview).  The code executed without problem the first time (when debugging), and thereafter my application won't start.  I deleted all the newly added code and debugged, but the errors stayed.  I even loaded my backup into Visual Studio, but no change.

I get the following errors and have no idea where to find the source of this problem:

> First-chance exception at 0x77cd708f in "app.name".exe: 0xC0000008: An
>   invalid handle was specified.  An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in System.dll.
>   Additional information: The type initializer for 'System.Net.ComNetOS'
>   threw an exception.

I re-installed Visual Studio and Framework 4.  I googled the errors, but nothing pointed me to the location causing the error. I don't believe it's in my code, because I built in try/catch blocks from the very start of the code, even using application events 'startup' and 'unhandledexception', but the app doesn't even start that I may catch the exception stacktrace.

Visual Studio indicates that no symbols are loaded for call stack frame and no source is available. I'm not aware of an error log that might provide details.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Debug + Exceptions, ensure that the Thrown check boxes are turned off.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hans. Everything is a mess; I get results now, and also new error messages.  Have no idea what to make of the results. An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in mscorlib.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary

Additional information: External component has thrown an exception.

Comment: It seems that all my problems came to an end by rebuilding the app with a new version number.  Thanks to the post at this link  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/4b70d85f-32b3-4246-849d-5c9653ddd6e8/.

Answer (score -1):

This should explain [First Chance Exceptions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14088/FIRST-CHANCE-Exceptions). and how to debug the .dll that causes them